# How to make child's height the same as parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my application I have a parent `div` and two other child `divs` inside this parent. One of these child div's has a set height while the other does not. I want to make the div who does not have a set height to be the same as the parent.

An illustration of what I am referring to can be seen in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ll3333/2Lxuj8wk/10/.

In this example, I want the div with class "child-2" to be the same height as the parent. For some reason, setting its height to "100%" does not seem to be working.

Thanks!

Comment: simply remove the height:100%, by default the element will stretch

Answer (score 0):

From [the MDN on `height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to `auto`. A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block.

The `100%` of the `height` property that you are setting is telling the element to take up `100%` of the parent's `height` (and this chains all the way to the first absolutely-specified `height`). However, you never actually *specify* the `height` of the parent element itself.

To resolve this, you'll need to set a `height` of `300px` on the parent. Note that this means that the other element could also make use of `height: 100%`, which would allow you to save on code (though this is not shown below).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height: 300px;
}

.child-1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40px;
}

.child-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, in my application, the height of the parent is determined by the height of "child-1", which has a dynamic height so I cannot just set the height of the parent to a fixed number. Is there any way to do this without hardcoding a height for the parent?

Answer (score 0):

you can add `align-items: stretch;` for `.parent` and remove `height: 100%;` in `.child-2`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.child-1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40px;
}

.child-2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
  </div>
</div>
```